# Usage of 'to' with ' All that '

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which one of the following statements is grammatically correct?

1. All that act would do is speed up the process of bringing justice to the victims
2. All that act would do is **to** speed up the process of bringing justice to the victims

If both are grammatically sound, please explain the difference between them.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

They are both grammatical, but the particle *to* can sometimes be omitted in constructions like this without any change in meaning. More common verbs that allow the omission are *dare, help* and *let*. If you are in any doubt, it’s probably safer to include it.